# tikzpicture only shows on the first page no matter how many times repeated?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics, amsart, tikz-pic

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=25pt] at (current page.north east)
              {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=25pt] at (current page.north east)
              {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Here I placed the tikzpicture code twice, but it only shows on the first page of the document. How can I make it show on every page of the document?

Comment: You should look into the `background` package.

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the problem when compiled. I get the image on pages 1 and 3 of the document, which is why you've asked for it to go. As @Alenanno says, use the `background` package to include it on every page. Or `wallpaper`, if `background` is still buggy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember to run it twice.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{everypage}

\AddEverypageHook{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
   \node[anchor=north east,inner sep=25pt] at (current page.north east)
              {\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}

\title{Title 1}
\maketitle

\lipsum

\newpage
\lipsum

\end{document}
```